# Converting std::span with dynamic extent to std::span with static extent

Tags: c++, c++20

I used to work with `gsl::span` from the Guidelines Support Library for some time. With `gsl::span`, it was possible to define a function taking a static extent and calling it with a `gsl::span` of dynamic extent, e.g.

```
void f(gsl::span<int, 5> s) { }
...
std::vector<int> v(100);
f(gsl::make_span(v).subspan(42, 5));    // Works
```

After porting the code to `std::span`, I noticed that this is no longer possible:

```
void f(std::span<int, 5> s) { }
...
std::vector<int> v(100);
f(std::span(v).subspan(42, 5));    // Does not work
```

Is there any reason for this difference? Is there any recommended way to convert a `std::span` with dynamic extent to a `std::span` with fixed extent?
Of course, it is possible to create a new span with fixed extent when calling the function:

```
f(std::span<int, 5>(&v[42], 5));
```

However, I think that the "subspan" variant is much better readable, it expresses the intention in a better way, *and* it allows appropriate range checking in a debug build.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is there any reason for this difference?

[P1976](https://wg21.link/p1976) goes through this at length. Fixed-extent spans have explicit constructors on purpose to try to alleviate undefined behavior, so `std::span<int>` (the type of `std::span(v).subspan(42, 5)`) is not convertible to `std::span<int, 5>`.

> Is there any recommended way to convert a std::span with dynamic extent to a std::span with fixed extent?

If both the offset and the count are constant expressions (which is true in this case), you can use the other overload of [`subspan()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/subspan):

```
f(std::span(v).subspan<42, 5>());
```

This overload exists the way it does so that you can take fixed-extent subspans of fixed-extent spans safely, but is less than ideally useful when wanting to take fixed-extent subspans of a dynamic-extent span, where ideally we'd just have wanted `std::span(v).subspan<5>(42)`.

For that case, you can instead use [`first()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/first) in conjunction with `subspan`:

```
f(std::span(v).subspan(42).first<5>());
```

Slightly longer, but gets the job done.

Or you can go full out and use the constructor:

```
f(std::span<int, 5>(std::span(v).subspan(42, 5)));
f(std::span<int, 5>(v.data() + 42, 5));
```

Comment: Many thanks for explaining all the details. In my real-world application, the offset is actually not a constant. However "f(std::span(v).subspan(42).first<5>());" does the job. "f(std::span<int, 5>(std::span(v).subspan(42, 5)));" is something which I've already tried before, but the compiler (MS VS 2019 16.6.5) does not accept it (it says that it can not convert the argument). So is this is bug in the compiler/library implementation?

Comment: @HolgerStrauss Yeah, library bug. gcc [gets it right](https://godbolt.org/z/14njqb).

Comment: Link to the MS bug report for reference purposes: [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1123813/conversion-of-stdspan-with-dynamic-extent-to-stdsp.html)

Comment: Given the option I would've liked to up-vote his answer twice since the `f(std::span(v).subspan(42).first<5>());` gem is *exactly* what I was looking for!

Comment: Thanks for all the explanations, I was trying to create a helper function to get the slice but did not manage to compile it with the first<X>() version any idea why it wouldn't work?
`code` template<typename T, unsigned int Size>
constexpr std::span<T,Size> slice(std::span<T> buf, unsigned int offset)
{
   //return buf.subspan(offset).first<Size>(); //doesn't compile on gcc
   return std::span<T,Size>(buf.subspan(offset, Size)); //works perfectly
}
and the Type T cannot be deduced but it's still easy to call
`code` const auto& part = slice<uint8_t, 8>(buffer, i);