# Transpose vector of vectors with views::zip

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, std-ranges, range-v3

Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61819663/11998382

This should be possible if we know the size of the outer vector at compile time.

You just have to write the c++ variadic-template equivalent of the following python code:

```py
def transpose(rng_of_rng):
    return zip(*rng_of_rng)
```

Comment: Also related https://stackoverflow.com/a/70918453/11998382

Comment: "*This should be possible if we know the size of the outer vector at compile time.*" How is this possible for `vector`?

Comment: @康桓瑋 I mean you are using `std::vector` as a `std::unique_ptr<std::array>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
template <std::size_t N, typename T>
auto transpose(std::span<T, N> rng_rng)
{
    return [&] <std::size_t... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>)
    {
        return  ranges::views::zip( rng_rng[I]... );
    }(std::make_integer_sequence<std::size_t, N>{});
}
```

And here it is in action: https://godbolt.org/z/oPdn89qnT

I found [barry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63053361/11998382) really useful when trying to convert a vector into a static-extent span.

---

On second thought, maybe this idea isn't so great because be get out a range of tuples. I'm only working with `N=10`, but I doubt it would be good to have really big tuple sizes.