# Structured binding for fixed-size span

Tags: c++, c++20, structured-bindings

After finding out you can [ergonomically convert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63053361) `std::vector`s into fix-sized `std::span`s, I thought I'd try out structured bindings for `std::vector`:

```cpp
auto _ = std::vector{ 1,2,3 };
std::span<int, 3> a = std::span(_).first<3>();
auto [b,c,d] = a;
```

But it's not working https://godbolt.org/z/nhrYn65dW

However, it seems from [P1024 Usability Enhancements for std::span](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1024r3.pdf) which was [accepted](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/128) that this should be legal

> Add structured binding support for fixed-size span? Unanimous consent

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This part of P1024 was undone by P2116. The reasoning comes from [LWG issue 3212](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3212), which details issues around the way `span` would need to interact with with `const` in a tuple-like interface. After some attempts at reworking the idea, they just decided to remove it.